# Actix web example from introduction gives run-time error thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Option::unwrap()` on a `None` value'

Tags: rust, actix-web

I am starting to use actix-web using the example from the getting started section of the actix web guide. When running the code I get a runtime error that appears to come from the actix framework.

Versions:

- win10
- rustc 1.33.0 (2aa4c46cf 2019-02-28)
- actix-web 0.7.18

This is the code:

```
extern crate actix_web;
use std::env;
use actix_web::{server, App, HttpRequest};

fn index(_req: &HttpRequest) -> &'static str {
    "Hello World!"
}

fn main() {
    env::set_var("RUST_BACKTRACE","1");

    server::new(
        || App::new()
            .resource("/", |r| r.f(index)))
        .bind("127.0.0.1:8088")
        .unwrap()
        .run();
}
```

It compiles ok, but I get the following backtrace, relevant lines in the backtrace appear to be line 11 where the panic seems to occur and line 73, which shows the call in my main function that ultimately leads to the panic.

I double checked that port 8088 is available. What am I doing wrong?

```
   Compiling hello_cargo v0.1.0 (D:\users\Jan Debeuckelaer\projects\hello_cargo)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 7.97s
     Running `target\debug\hello_cargo.exe`
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Option::unwrap()` on a `None` value', src\libcore\option.rs:345:21
stack backtrace:
   0: std::sys::windows::backtrace::set_frames
             at /rustc/2aa4c46cfdd726e97360c2734835aa3515e8c858\/src\libstd\sys\windows\backtrace\mod.rs:94
   1: std::sys::windows::backtrace::unwind_backtrace
             at /rustc/2aa4c46cfdd726e97360c2734835aa3515e8c858\/src\libstd\sys\windows\backtrace\mod.rs:81
   2: std::sys_common::backtrace::_print
             at /rustc/2aa4c46cfdd726e97360c2734835aa3515e8c858\/src\libstd\sys_common\backtrace.rs:70
   3: std::sys_common::backtrace::print
             at /rustc/2aa4c46cfdd726e97360c2734835aa3515e8c858\/src\libstd\sys_common\backtrace.rs:58
   4: std::panicking::default_hook::{{closure}}
             at /rustc/2aa4c46cfdd726e97360c2734835aa3515e8c858\/src\libstd\panicking.rs:200
   5: std::panicking::default_hook
             at /rustc/2aa4c46cfdd726e97360c2734835aa3515e8c858\/src\libstd\panicking.rs:215
   6: std::panicking::rust_panic_with_hook
             at /rustc/2aa4c46cfdd726e97360c2734835aa3515e8c858\/src\libstd\panicking.rs:478
   7: std::panicking::continue_panic_fmt
             at /rustc/2aa4c46cfdd726e97360c2734835aa3515e8c858\/src\libstd\panicking.rs:385
   8: std::panicking::rust_begin_panic
             at /rustc/2aa4c46cfdd726e97360c2734835aa3515e8c858\/src\libstd\panicking.rs:312
   9: core::panicking::panic_fmt
             at /rustc/2aa4c46cfdd726e97360c2734835aa3515e8c858\/src\libcore\panicking.rs:85
  10: core::panicking::panic
             at /rustc/2aa4c46cfdd726e97360c2734835aa3515e8c858\/src\libcore\panicking.rs:49
  11: core::option::Option<(mio::poll::Registration, mio::poll::SetReadiness)*>::unwrap<(mio::poll::Registration, mio::poll::SetReadiness)*>
             at /rustc/2aa4c46cfdd726e97360c2734835aa3515e8c858\src\libcore\macros.rs:10
  12: tokio_signal::windows::global_init
             at C:\Users\Jan Debeuckelaer\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\tokio-signal-0.2.8\src\windows.rs:165
  13: tokio_signal::windows::{{impl}}::new::{{closure}}
             at C:\Users\Jan Debeuckelaer\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\tokio-signal-0.2.8\src\windows.rs:118
  14: std::sync::once::{{impl}}::call_once::{{closure}}<closure>
             at /rustc/2aa4c46cfdd726e97360c2734835aa3515e8c858\src\libstd\sync\once.rs:220
  15: std::sync::once::Once::call_inner
             at /rustc/2aa4c46cfdd726e97360c2734835aa3515e8c858\/src\libstd\sync\once.rs:387
  16: std::sync::once::Once::call_once<closure>
             at /rustc/2aa4c46cfdd726e97360c2734835aa3515e8c858\src\libstd\sync\once.rs:220
  17: tokio_signal::windows::Event::new
             at C:\Users\Jan Debeuckelaer\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\tokio-signal-0.2.8\src\windows.rs:117
  18: tokio_signal::windows::Event::ctrl_c_handle
             at C:\Users\Jan Debeuckelaer\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\tokio-signal-0.2.8\src\windows.rs:96
  19: tokio_signal::ctrl_c_handle::ctrl_c_imp::{{closure}}
             at C:\Users\Jan Debeuckelaer\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\tokio-signal-0.2.8\src\lib.rs:137
  20: futures::future::lazy::Lazy<closure, futures::future::map::Map<alloc::boxed::Box<Future>, closure>>::get<closure,futures::future::map::Map<alloc::boxed::Box<Future>, closure>>
             at C:\Users\Jan Debeuckelaer\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\futures-0.1.25\src\future\lazy.rs:64
  21: futures::future::lazy::{{impl}}::poll<closure,futures::future::map::Map<alloc::boxed::Box<Future>, closure>>
             at C:\Users\Jan Debeuckelaer\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\futures-0.1.25\src\future\lazy.rs:82
  22: futures::future::{{impl}}::poll<Future>
             at C:\Users\Jan Debeuckelaer\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\futures-0.1.25\src\future\mod.rs:113
  23: futures::future::map_err::{{impl}}::poll<(),alloc::boxed::Box<Future>,closure>
             at C:\Users\Jan Debeuckelaer\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\futures-0.1.25\src\future\map_err.rs:30
  24: actix::fut::{{impl}}::poll<futures::future::map_err::MapErr<alloc::boxed::Box<Future>, closure>,actix::actors::signal::ProcessSignals>
             at C:\Users\Jan Debeuckelaer\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\actix-0.7.9\src\fut\mod.rs:389
  25: actix::fut::map::{{impl}}::poll<(),actix::fut::FutureWrap<futures::future::map_err::MapErr<alloc::boxed::Box<Future>, closure>, actix::actors::signal::ProcessSignals>,closure>
             at C:\Users\Jan Debeuckelaer\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\actix-0.7.9\src\fut\map.rs:38
  26: actix::fut::{{impl}}::poll<ActorFuture>
             at C:\Users\Jan Debeuckelaer\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\actix-0.7.9\src\fut\mod.rs:313
  27: actix::contextimpl::{{impl}}::poll<actix::actors::signal::ProcessSignals,actix::context::Context<actix::actors::signal::ProcessSignals>>
             at C:\Users\Jan Debeuckelaer\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\actix-0.7.9\src\contextimpl.rs:355
  28: actix::supervisor::{{impl}}::poll<actix::actors::signal::ProcessSignals>
             at C:\Users\Jan Debeuckelaer\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\actix-0.7.9\src\supervisor.rs:147
  29: futures::future::{{impl}}::poll<actix::supervisor::Supervisor<actix::actors::signal::ProcessSignals>>
             at C:\Users\Jan Debeuckelaer\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\futures-0.1.25\src\future\mod.rs:113
  30: futures::future::{{impl}}::poll<Future>
             at C:\Users\Jan Debeuckelaer\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\futures-0.1.25\src\future\mod.rs:113
  31: futures::task_impl::{{impl}}::poll_future_notify::{{closure}}<alloc::boxed::Box<Future>,tokio_current_thread::scheduler::Notify<tokio_reactor::Handle>>
             at C:\Users\Jan Debeuckelaer\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\futures-0.1.25\src\task_impl\mod.rs:326
  32: futures::task_impl::{{impl}}::enter::{{closure}}<alloc::boxed::Box<Future>,closure,core::result::Result<futures::poll::Async<()>, ()>>
             at C:\Users\Jan Debeuckelaer\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\futures-0.1.25\src\task_impl\mod.rs:396
  33: futures::task_impl::std::set<closure,core::result::Result<futures::poll::Async<()>, ()>>
             at C:\Users\Jan Debeuckelaer\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\futures-0.1.25\src\task_impl\std\mod.rs:78
  34: futures::task_impl::Spawn<alloc::boxed::Box<Future>>::enter<alloc::boxed::Box<Future>,closure,core::result::Result<futures::poll::Async<()>, ()>>
             at C:\Users\Jan Debeuckelaer\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\futures-0.1.25\src\task_impl\mod.rs:396
  35: futures::task_impl::Spawn<alloc::boxed::Box<Future>>::poll_fn_notify<alloc::boxed::Box<Future>,tokio_current_thread::scheduler::Notify<tokio_reactor::Handle>,closure,core::result::Result<futures::poll::Async<()>, ()>>
             at C:\Users\Jan Debeuckelaer\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\futures-0.1.25\src\task_impl\mod.rs:288
  36: futures::task_impl::Spawn<alloc::boxed::Box<Future>>::poll_future_notify<alloc::boxed::Box<Future>,tokio_current_thread::scheduler::Notify<tokio_reactor::Handle>>
             at C:\Users\Jan Debeuckelaer\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\futures-0.1.25\src\task_impl\mod.rs:326
  37: tokio_current_thread::scheduler::Scheduled<tokio_reactor::Handle>::tick<tokio_reactor::Handle>
             at C:\Users\Jan Debeuckelaer\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\tokio-current-thread-0.1.6\src\scheduler.rs:351
  38: tokio_current_thread::scheduler::{{impl}}::tick::{{closure}}<tokio_reactor::Handle>
             at C:\Users\Jan Debeuckelaer\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\tokio-current-thread-0.1.6\src\scheduler.rs:330
  39: tokio_current_thread::{{impl}}::enter::{{closure}}::{{closure}}<tokio_reactor::Handle,closure,bool>
             at C:\Users\Jan Debeuckelaer\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\tokio-current-thread-0.1.6\src\lib.rs:788
  40: tokio_current_thread::CurrentRunner::set_spawn<closure,bool>
             at C:\Users\Jan Debeuckelaer\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\tokio-current-thread-0.1.6\src\lib.rs:825
  41: tokio_current_thread::{{impl}}::enter::{{closure}}<tokio_reactor::Handle,closure,bool>
             at C:\Users\Jan Debeuckelaer\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\tokio-current-thread-0.1.6\src\lib.rs:788
  42: std::thread::local::LocalKey<tokio_current_thread::CurrentRunner>::try_with<tokio_current_thread::CurrentRunner,closure,bool>
             at /rustc/2aa4c46cfdd726e97360c2734835aa3515e8c858\src\libstd\thread\local.rs:299
  43: std::thread::local::LocalKey<tokio_current_thread::CurrentRunner>::with<tokio_current_thread::CurrentRunner,closure,bool>
             at /rustc/2aa4c46cfdd726e97360c2734835aa3515e8c858\src\libstd\thread\local.rs:245
  44: tokio_current_thread::Borrow<tokio_reactor::Handle>::enter<tokio_reactor::Handle,closure,bool>
             at C:\Users\Jan Debeuckelaer\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\tokio-current-thread-0.1.6\src\lib.rs:786
  45: tokio_current_thread::scheduler::Scheduler<tokio_reactor::Handle>::tick<tokio_reactor::Handle>
             at C:\Users\Jan Debeuckelaer\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\tokio-current-thread-0.1.6\src\scheduler.rs:330
  46: tokio_current_thread::Entered<tokio_timer::timer::Timer<tokio_reactor::Reactor, tokio_timer::clock::clock::Clock>>::tick<tokio_timer::timer::Timer<tokio_reactor::Reactor, tokio_timer::clock::clock::Clock>>
             at C:\Users\Jan Debeuckelaer\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\tokio-current-thread-0.1.6\src\lib.rs:612
  47: tokio_current_thread::Entered<tokio_timer::timer::Timer<tokio_reactor::Reactor, tokio_timer::clock::clock::Clock>>::block_on<tokio_timer::timer::Timer<tokio_reactor::Reactor, tokio_timer::clock::clock::Clock>,futures::sync::oneshot::Receiver<i32>>
             at C:\Users\Jan Debeuckelaer\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\tokio-current-thread-0.1.6\src\lib.rs:502
  48: tokio::runtime::current_thread::runtime::{{impl}}::block_on::{{closure}}<futures::sync::oneshot::Receiver<i32>>
             at C:\Users\Jan Debeuckelaer\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\tokio-0.1.18\src\runtime\current_thread\runtime.rs:200
  49: tokio::runtime::current_thread::runtime::{{impl}}::enter::{{closure}}::{{closure}}::{{closure}}::{{closure}}<closure,core::result::Result<i32, futures::sync::oneshot::Canceled>>
             at C:\Users\Jan Debeuckelaer\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\tokio-0.1.18\src\runtime\current_thread\runtime.rs:241
  50: tokio_executor::global::with_default::{{closure}}<tokio_current_thread::TaskExecutor,closure,core::result::Result<i32, futures::sync::oneshot::Canceled>>
             at C:\Users\Jan Debeuckelaer\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\tokio-executor-0.1.7\src\global.rs:209
  51: std::thread::local::LocalKey<core::cell::Cell<tokio_executor::global::State>>::try_with<core::cell::Cell<tokio_executor::global::State>,closure,core::result::Result<i32, futures::sync::oneshot::Canceled>>
             at /rustc/2aa4c46cfdd726e97360c2734835aa3515e8c858\src\libstd\thread\local.rs:299
  52: std::thread::local::LocalKey<core::cell::Cell<tokio_executor::global::State>>::with<core::cell::Cell<tokio_executor::global::State>,closure,core::result::Result<i32, futures::sync::oneshot::Canceled>>
             at /rustc/2aa4c46cfdd726e97360c2734835aa3515e8c858\src\libstd\thread\local.rs:245
  53: tokio_executor::global::with_default<tokio_current_thread::TaskExecutor,closure,core::result::Result<i32, futures::sync::oneshot::Canceled>>
             at C:\Users\Jan Debeuckelaer\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\tokio-executor-0.1.7\src\global.rs:178
  54: tokio::runtime::current_thread::runtime::{{impl}}::enter::{{closure}}::{{closure}}::{{closure}}<closure,core::result::Result<i32, futures::sync::oneshot::Canceled>>
             at C:\Users\Jan Debeuckelaer\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\tokio-0.1.18\src\runtime\current_thread\runtime.rs:239
  55: tokio_timer::timer::handle::with_default::{{closure}}<closure,core::result::Result<i32, futures::sync::oneshot::Canceled>>
             at C:\Users\Jan Debeuckelaer\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\tokio-timer-0.2.10\src\timer\handle.rs:94
  56: std::thread::local::LocalKey<core::cell::RefCell<core::option::Option<tokio_timer::timer::handle::HandlePriv>>>::try_with<core::cell::RefCell<core::option::Option<tokio_timer::timer::handle::HandlePriv>>,closure,core::result::Result<i32, futures::sync::oneshot::Canceled>>
             at /rustc/2aa4c46cfdd726e97360c2734835aa3515e8c858\src\libstd\thread\local.rs:299
  57: std::thread::local::LocalKey<core::cell::RefCell<core::option::Option<tokio_timer::timer::handle::HandlePriv>>>::with<core::cell::RefCell<core::option::Option<tokio_timer::timer::handle::HandlePriv>>,closure,core::result::Result<i32, futures::sync::oneshot::Canceled>>
             at /rustc/2aa4c46cfdd726e97360c2734835aa3515e8c858\src\libstd\thread\local.rs:245
  58: tokio_timer::timer::handle::with_default<closure,core::result::Result<i32, futures::sync::oneshot::Canceled>>
             at C:\Users\Jan Debeuckelaer\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\tokio-timer-0.2.10\src\timer\handle.rs:81
  59: tokio::runtime::current_thread::runtime::{{impl}}::enter::{{closure}}::{{closure}}<closure,core::result::Result<i32, futures::sync::oneshot::Canceled>>
             at C:\Users\Jan Debeuckelaer\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\tokio-0.1.18\src\runtime\current_thread\runtime.rs:232
  60: tokio_timer::clock::clock::with_default::{{closure}}<closure,core::result::Result<i32, futures::sync::oneshot::Canceled>>
             at C:\Users\Jan Debeuckelaer\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\tokio-timer-0.2.10\src\clock\clock.rs:141
  61: std::thread::local::LocalKey<core::cell::Cell<core::option::Option<const tokio_timer::clock::clock::Clock*>>>::try_with<core::cell::Cell<core::option::Option<const tokio_timer::clock::clock::Clock*>>,closure,core::result::Result<i32, futures::sync::oneshot::Canceled>>
             at /rustc/2aa4c46cfdd726e97360c2734835aa3515e8c858\src\libstd\thread\local.rs:299
  62: std::thread::local::LocalKey<core::cell::Cell<core::option::Option<const tokio_timer::clock::clock::Clock*>>>::with<core::cell::Cell<core::option::Option<const tokio_timer::clock::clock::Clock*>>,closure,core::result::Result<i32, futures::sync::oneshot::Canceled>>
             at /rustc/2aa4c46cfdd726e97360c2734835aa3515e8c858\src\libstd\thread\local.rs:245
  63: tokio_timer::clock::clock::with_default<closure,core::result::Result<i32, futures::sync::oneshot::Canceled>>
             at C:\Users\Jan Debeuckelaer\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\tokio-timer-0.2.10\src\clock\clock.rs:124
  64: tokio::runtime::current_thread::runtime::{{impl}}::enter::{{closure}}<closure,core::result::Result<i32, futures::sync::oneshot::Canceled>>
             at C:\Users\Jan Debeuckelaer\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\tokio-0.1.18\src\runtime\current_thread\runtime.rs:231
  65: tokio_reactor::with_default::{{closure}}<closure,core::result::Result<i32, futures::sync::oneshot::Canceled>>
             at C:\Users\Jan Debeuckelaer\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\tokio-reactor-0.1.9\src\lib.rs:237
  66: std::thread::local::LocalKey<core::cell::RefCell<core::option::Option<tokio_reactor::HandlePriv>>>::try_with<core::cell::RefCell<core::option::Option<tokio_reactor::HandlePriv>>,closure,core::result::Result<i32, futures::sync::oneshot::Canceled>>
             at /rustc/2aa4c46cfdd726e97360c2734835aa3515e8c858\src\libstd\thread\local.rs:299
  67: std::thread::local::LocalKey<core::cell::RefCell<core::option::Option<tokio_reactor::HandlePriv>>>::with<core::cell::RefCell<core::option::Option<tokio_reactor::HandlePriv>>,closure,core::result::Result<i32, futures::sync::oneshot::Canceled>>
             at /rustc/2aa4c46cfdd726e97360c2734835aa3515e8c858\src\libstd\thread\local.rs:245
  68: tokio_reactor::with_default<closure,core::result::Result<i32, futures::sync::oneshot::Canceled>>
             at C:\Users\Jan Debeuckelaer\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\tokio-reactor-0.1.9\src\lib.rs:217
  69: tokio::runtime::current_thread::runtime::Runtime::enter<closure,core::result::Result<i32, futures::sync::oneshot::Canceled>>
             at C:\Users\Jan Debeuckelaer\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\tokio-0.1.18\src\runtime\current_thread\runtime.rs:230
  70: tokio::runtime::current_thread::runtime::Runtime::block_on<futures::sync::oneshot::Receiver<i32>>
             at C:\Users\Jan Debeuckelaer\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\tokio-0.1.18\src\runtime\current_thread\runtime.rs:198
  71: actix::system::SystemRunner::run
             at C:\Users\Jan Debeuckelaer\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\actix-0.7.9\src\system.rs:174
  72: actix_web::server::http::HttpServer<actix_web::application::App<()>, closure>::run<actix_web::application::App<()>,closure>
             at C:\Users\Jan Debeuckelaer\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\actix-web-0.7.18\src\server\http.rs:539
  73: hello_cargo::main
             at .\src\main.rs:12
  74: std::rt::lang_start::{{closure}}<()>
             at /rustc/2aa4c46cfdd726e97360c2734835aa3515e8c858\src\libstd\rt.rs:64
  75: std::rt::lang_start_internal::{{closure}}
             at /rustc/2aa4c46cfdd726e97360c2734835aa3515e8c858\/src\libstd\rt.rs:49
  76: std::panicking::try::do_call<closure,i32>
             at /rustc/2aa4c46cfdd726e97360c2734835aa3515e8c858\/src\libstd\panicking.rs:297
  77: panic_unwind::__rust_maybe_catch_panic
             at /rustc/2aa4c46cfdd726e97360c2734835aa3515e8c858\/src\libpanic_unwind\lib.rs:92
             at /rustc/2aa4c46cfdd726e97360c2734835aa3515e8c858\/src\libstd\panicking.rs:276
  79: std::panic::catch_unwind
             at /rustc/2aa4c46cfdd726e97360c2734835aa3515e8c858\/src\libstd\panic.rs:388
  80: std::rt::lang_start_internal
             at /rustc/2aa4c46cfdd726e97360c2734835aa3515e8c858\/src\libstd\rt.rs:48
  81: std::rt::lang_start<()>
             at /rustc/2aa4c46cfdd726e97360c2734835aa3515e8c858\src\libstd\rt.rs:64
  83: invoke_main
             at d:\agent\_work\1\s\src\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_common.inl:78
  84: __scrt_common_main_seh
             at d:\agent\_work\1\s\src\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_common.inl:288
  85: BaseThreadInitThunk
  86: RtlUserThreadStart
Panic in Arbiter thread, shutting down system.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this too and I think this is related to this two issues in tokio lib:

- [tokio-signal is broken on Windows since version 0.1.18](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio/issues/999)
- [tokio-signal: windows DriverTask never terminates](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio/issues/1000)

Comment: @why issue 1000 ?

Comment: I read somewhere that these two things are related, on discord channel probably. Not sure.

Comment: doesn't look linked, just found in the same time "**On an unrelated note**, the ctrl-c example still doesn't work quite right, even with the fix above, because we're blocking on all futures spawned into the runtime, which includes an immortal driver task which intercepts the OS ctrl-c events. I want to look into refactoring the driver task to possibly die on it's own if there are no more ctrl-c listeners" https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio/issues/999#issuecomment-475901027

Comment: Thanks for your insights. I see that the tokio team submitted a PR to fix the underlying issue. I'll switch to Linux for now.